# How to discover & play podcasts in Android Application

Tags: android, podcast

I would like to develop an Android Application that can discovers and plays any available **podcasts**.

There seems to be a shortage of **Podcast directories** that have working links and I cannot find any information on how to retrieve podcast metadata to assist in describing the podcast content and duration.

Is it that this information is not freely available?

Are there any Java libraries that simplify podcast playback and metadata retrieval?

Does each podcast site (Link) require unique customised processing?

Comment: Stackoverflow DOWNVOTER: You have the time to read my question and then downvote but you lack the courage to explain why? What value has your downvote delivered? I have a genuine interest to develop an android application that can consume any podcast and I require some assistance. Why does that qualify for a downvote? How does that downvote assist me or the stackoverflow community in general?

Comment: Just stay cool. There are so many unreasonable downvoters here. Don't waste your time for it. You can't argue with them.